# Remove overlaps from lubridate intervals

Tags: r, lubridate

I created a set of intervals using `lubridate::int_diff` but this gives intervals that share boundaries. For example:

```
2021-09-01 UTC--2021-09-07 UTC 
2021-09-07 UTC--2021-10-10 UTC
2021-10-10 UTC--2021-10-24 UTC
2021-10-24 UTC--2021-11-30 UTC
```

I would like to get this instead -- intervals without shared boundaries:

```
2021-09-01 UTC--2021-09-06 UTC 
2021-09-07 UTC--2021-10-09 UTC
2021-10-10 UTC--2021-10-23 UTC
2021-10-24 UTC--2021-11-30 UTC
```

Comment: Need: `library` call, data, code.

Comment: is that one column or two, you need to better explain